# Move RecyclerView together with the Swipe Refresh Layout indicator (like Instagram pull to refresh)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout, pull-to-refresh

I want to move `Recyclerview` together with the Swipe Refresh Layout indicator (do not place the indicator above the Recyclerview, but Recyclerview should be appeared below of swipe refresh indicator).

I have implemented a recyclerView inside a `SwipeRefreshLayout`. The corresponding XML is below.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_news">

   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
       android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
       android:scrollbars="vertical"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Currently swipe looks like this:

[image: See this picture]

I want something like this but I don't want to use any third-party library:
[image: See this pic]